# How to change the scale of axes in line chart using d3.js?

Tags: d3.js, linechart

I want to change the scale of X-axis in a line-chart so that it can show 20,000 and more values at a time. Please help me with this.
My line chart has two columns(ID and TIME). ID values are 1,2,3 and so on upto 20132. TIME values vary from 0 to 525. I am unable to draw the line chart with these values. Could you please help me with changing the scale of axes?

Answer (score 0):

In what way are you unable to draw the line chart? You would want to let the x-axis be a function of your data, using D3s' built-in scale functions. See [this tutorial](http://synthesis.sbecker.net/articles/2012/07/15/learning-d3-part-5-axes) for further guidelines.

**EDIT** :

So, let's say you have some data stored in the variable `data`. First and foremost, you need a scale that recalculates each data value to fit your SVG container. For example:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.id; })]) //Convert the id-values...
    .range([0, 960]); //...to a range from 0 to 960.
```

The next step is to construct an axis which takes its data from the range of a scale, like so:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x);
```

The final (well, except for some mandatory styling afterwards) step is to link the axis to your SVG container. Let's say you named the container `svg`. Then:

```
svg.append('g')
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .call(xAxis);
```